# Prism+MVVM: How to refresh control's UI without the binding property change?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

Now I want to refresh the control's UI with the binding property in the ViewModel unchanged, any idea to make it?

Explain more:

The detail of this issue is that the control's binding property(datasource) remains, but one other property in the ViewModel which concerning the UI of the control changes. When that property changes, I need the UI to refresh.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'refresh'? How does that single property affect the UI? What should be different after it changes?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet  The ViewModel imples the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, when a property which is binding to control like datagridview changes, the method OnPropertyChanged can notice the control to refresh the UI like adding a new record into the datagridview.

Comment: Raise `PropertyChanged` event and UI should update. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `INotifyPropertyChanged` then you simply need to raise the PropertyChanged event supplying the name of the property that the control is bound to.
e.g.

```
var localHandler = PropertyChanged;
if (localHandler != null)
{
    localHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("YOURPROPERTYNAME"));
}
```

In one of your comments on your question you mention having to raise `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify a control that its ItemsSource has changed. If this is what you want to do then I suggest binding to an `ObservableCollection` as it will handle keeping the control displaying the Items up to date.